# flutter symbolize crashes on execute

Tags: flutter, obfuscation

Following the docs to obfuscate at https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

Generated symbol mapping file via:

`flutter build apk --shrink --obfuscate --release --split-debug-info=out/symbols`

This appears to generate the 3 symbol files correctly.
After throwing an exception and saving to file, when running this command:

`flutter symbolize --input=stacktrace.txt --debug-info=out/symbols/app.android-arm64.symbols`

It results in this error:

`Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "type 'Utf8Decoder' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, String>' of 'streamTransformer'".`

I don't see any known issues about this. Is there a solution or workaround?

Any Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just discovered and fixed

> **flutter symbolize is broken #55214**   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55214

and

> **[flutter_tools] fix type error in symbolize #55212** https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/55212